# Why am I not able to parse valid XML straight from the Salesforce Documentation, but JSON works fine?

Tags: rest, xml, httppost, restresource

On this particular page:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_rest_methods.htm

About halfway down, you'll see a method which I have included in my class

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/Cases/*')
global class MyClassPostStudy{

@HttpPost
    global static void myPostMethod(String s1, Integer i1, Boolean b1, String s2){
        system.debug('this hit');
    }
}
```

By going to Workbench and using the REST Explorer - I'm able to parse the JSON in the example just fine.

```
{
  "s1" : "my first string",
  "i1" : 123,
  "s2" : "my second string",
  "b1" : false
}
```

However I'm getting an error when I parse the XML example:

```
<request>
  <s1>my first string</s1>
  <i1>123</i1>
  <s2>my second string</s2>
  <b1>false</b1>
</request>
```

message: Unexpected character ('<' (code 60)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null') at [line:1, column:2]
errorCode: JSON_PARSER_ERROR

[image: Error Screenshot]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out - I needed to go into the 'Headers' button in Workbench and change the

```
Content-Type: application/JSON; charset=UTF-8 
Accept: application/JSON
```

to

```
Content-Type: application/xml; charset=UTF-8
Accept: application/xml
```

[image]